# Advice on duplicating a site under React Js

Tags: reactjs, git, amazon-web-services, github, aws-amplify

I need a little advice before I start work.

So I have been developing a site under React for a client for 2 years now.

My client wants to duplicate this site to create 3 additional brands, the architecture, the design is the same, just the content and the logos change.

**So for you is this:**

1 - I duplicate in several github repos

**Where**

2 - I simply create several branches

Thanks

Comment: 3. Create one universal architecture with switches on config.

Comment: This is entirely a matter of opinion and the nuances of your organization and/or project. I do agree with phd, though. No need for _either_ of those. Make your branding and content abstract. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depends.
Option A, copy-paste your project to X other projects will make it easy to start and you can finish it in a day, BUT... every time you'll have to fix a bug you will need to do it in each repo and they'll diverge.

Option B, is to build front-end and an API.
The UI will be the same for all the projects but the API will return different data based on the client.

Option C, create a configuration file that you can modify based on the customer.

I believe that Option A will be the simplest & fastest one to get started with. You'll pay the price as you grow, but if you don't need to maintain the projects in the future I would go with it.

If you're going to maintain those projects for a long time you might want to consider refactoring the projects to a dynamic backend that returns the data based on the client.

Option C, it's a pretty good compromise between A and B.